# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, i have tried many ways

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for(var key in result)
{
    var html = '';
    html += '<li class="item item_chat">' +
    '<div class="product-img">' +
    '<img src="' + base_url + '/assets/img/noimage.png" alt="Product 
      Image" class="img-size-50">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="product-info">' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewGroupBody(this,' + 
       result[key].id + ',' + result[key].name + ');" class="product- 
       title">' + result[key].name +
    '<span class="badge badge-danger float-right"> Group </span></a>' +
    '<span class="product-description"> Message </span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>';
    $('#messageListDashGroups').append(html);
}
```

I am getting error on this line in onclick function

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewGroupBody(this,' + 
           result[key].id + ',' + result[key].name + ');" class="product- 
           title">' + result[key].name +
```

Before i use two arguments

```
onclick="viewCusBody(this,' + id + ')"
```

But now i add an extra argument so i am having issue

Comment: Use a template literal instead for readability, and attach the event listener properly with `on('click'` or something so you don't have to deal with escaping

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Always look at the rendered output. `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewGroupBody(this,123,Item Name);" ...` well that's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

> Template literals are string literals allowing ***embedded expressions***. You can use ***multi-line strings*** and ***string interpolation*** features with them.

**Demo:**

```js
var base_url = "test.com";
var result_id = "some_id";
var result_name = "jhon";

var html = `<li class="item item_chat">
            <div class="product-img">
            <img src="${base_url}/assets/img/noimage.png" alt="Product 
            Image" class="img-size-50">
            </div>
            <div class="product-info">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewGroupBody(this,'${result_id}','${result_name}');" class="product- title">${result_name}
            <span class="badge badge-danger float-right"> Group </span></a>
            <span class="product-description"> Message </span>
            </div>
            </li>`;
$('#messageListDashGroups').append(html);
    
function viewGroupBody(el, id, name){
  console.log(id)
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messageListDashGroups"></div>
```

**For IE:** Try the traditional way by changing

```
onclick="viewGroupBody(this,' + result[key].id + ',' + result[key].name + ');"
```

To

```
onclick=viewGroupBody(this,"'+result['key'].id+'","'+result['key'].name+'")
```

```js
var base_url = "test.com";
var result = {key:{id: "some_id", name:"john"}};

var html = '';
html += '<li class="item item_chat">' +
'<div class="product-img">' +
'<img src="' + base_url + '/assets/img/noimage.png" alt="Product Image" class="img-size-50">' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="product-info">' +
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=viewGroupBody(this,"'+result['key'].id+'","'+result['key'].name+'"); class="product- title">'+
'<span class="badge badge-danger float-right"> Group </span></a>' +
'<span class="product-description"> Message </span>' +
'</div>' +
'</li>';
$('#messageListDashGroups').append(html);

function viewGroupBody(el, id, name){
  console.log(id)
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messageListDashGroups"></div>
```

Comment: @IkramKhizer, please see browser support....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility